# ListView duplicate Items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a Fragment (Movies) that has a ListView inside, when I go to another Fragment (Movie Detail) and come back (Movies) through Ancestral Navigation the ListView duplicate the items (movies), I'm using Volley to populate the ListView. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Here is my code:

VolleyAdapter:

```
public class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public VolleyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movies = movies;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_lista_barraca_nomeTextView);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Movie movie = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(movie.getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTextView;
}
}
```

MoviesFragment:

```
public class MoviesFragment extends ListFragment {
private VolleyAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<Movie> mMovies;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      mMovies = MovieDAO.get(getActivity()).getMovies();
      mAdapter = new VolleyAdapter(getActivity(), mMovies);
      setListAdapter(mAdapter);

      JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, 
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response {
              // create movie..
              mMovies.add(movie);
              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
              ...
      });
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

    }
```

Comment: What does MovieDAO.get(getActivity()).getMovies() do?

Comment: If you go to another fragment again, and came back, will it be populated by 3 times, or just 2? (so Movies -> Details -> Movies (2*items) -> Details -> Movies shows 2 times, or 3 times the elements?)

Comment: MovieDAO.get(getActivity()).getMovies() just return an ArrayList of movies, in that case null, but after request of Volley I insert some items in it

Comment: shows 3 times, 4 times,.. etc..